# how create custom shape in android jetpack compose?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, shapes

[How can I make a shape like this?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xT2Gy.png)

Comment: Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70822931/17787605) or [here](https://blog.devgenius.io/custom-shapes-in-jetpack-compose-deep-dive-b987a52c743c)

Comment: Can you please read about [the problems with images of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) and then [edit] to add a description in words of what you are looking for.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

I see there two ways how I would've done this:

1. You can create @Composable function with Canvases ([official guideline](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/graphics/draw/overview), [article on Medium](https://medium.com/falabellatechnology/jetpack-compose-canvas-8aee73eab393)), if you need to use tab of this folder-like shape

```kotlin
// Usage:
@Composable
fun Somewhere() {
  FolderLikeCard(
    topTailContent = {
      // for example, your tab will just be, without content, only for shape
      Box(modifier = Modifier.size(64.dp, 12.dp))
    },
    mainContent = {
      // main content
    }
  )
}


// Implementation:
@Composable
fun FolderLikeCard(
  topTailContent: @Composable () -> Unit,
  mainContent: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
  val cornerSize = 4.dp // for example
  Column {
    Row {
      Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))
      Box {
        Canvas {
          TODO("draw with help of links above tab's outline (using drawArc maybe)")
        }
        Box(
          modifier = Modifier.padding(left = cornerSize, top = cornerSize, right = cornerSize),
          content = topTailContent
        )
      }
    }
    Box {
      Canvas {
        TODO("draw main part outline")
      }
      Box(
        modifier = Modifier.padding(left = cornerSize, bottom = cornerSize, right = cornerSize),
        content = mainContent
      )
    }
  }
}
```

+ I feel it can be refactored with help of [`Modifier.drawBehind`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/draw/package-summary#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).drawBehind(kotlin.Function1)) method

2. Create an actual Shape for using it in `Modifier.background(color = yourColor, shape = FolderLikeShape(tabHeight, tabWidth, ...))` method, [link to the article that I read some time ago](https://juliensalvi.medium.com/custom-shape-with-jetpack-compose-1cb48a991d42), [+ linked question helps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70742521/customize-shapes-with-jetpack-compose-android?noredirect=1&lq=1), but I don’t see how you can then put the content there so far, if you need it, then I hope the following commentators will help with this.